# Database disappearing on OpenShift (OSE) running Postgres and Rails 4 / Ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift-enterprise

I have Ruby (2) on Rails (4) app deployed on OpenShift Enterprise running a Postgres database. After initial deployment the app worked perfectly, information was persisted in the database, routing was working, all the tests were passing - everything was good.

Then I deployed some new changes with `git push openshift master`. When I went back to the app it was still running, but all the database content (including table structure) was gone.

The output from the `push` was clean. I didn't write any hooks, or have any funky cron jobs running. I could repeat the process, rebuilding the database, and watch it get blown away on every deployment. This problem was not occurring in my local instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Make sure you have a `.openshift` directory at your project's root, use this as an example: https://github.com/openshift/rails4-example

Here's what was going on.

When I created the Rails app I didn't know where I would end up deploying it. Consequently I didn't start with an [OpenShift Rails skeleton app](https://github.com/openshift/rails4-example) or by using `rhc app create ruby-X.X.X -a railsX`.

When I was told to deploy on open shift I just configured `rhc` and set up an openshift `git remote`.

This meant there was no `.openshift` directory in my project's root. Once I cloned https://github.com/openshift/rails4-example and moved that project's `.openshift` directory into my project root I was able to deploy without losing my database.

Comment: I'd love to know WHY this is/was the case, if anyone has any ideas!